# Can Laravel Dusk Run in a CLI Application?

Tags: laravel, command-line, laravel-dusk

This question technically had two parts:

- is the chrome driver of Dusk functional in a CLI app?
- would Laravel Zero be able to work with Dusk?

I would like to create a command line app that runs some personal banking automation. I know Dusk can be used with external sites, but I don't have experience in Dusk with CLI apps and I've not yet used Laravel Zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to both questions. Laravel Dusk accepts a `--headless` option for running a headless version of chrome.

Within the `DuskTestCase` class, you can supply the arguements needed like:

```
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
   '--disable-gpu',
   '--headless',
   '--no-sandbox',
]);
```

Comment: Please share more code about this..
i create a cron job in which i want to start process by calling a function from crawlercontroller in cron job